# How to calculate how much time is remaning 3 days from created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to show to the user how much time is remaning in his profile. Generally I want to do it 3 days before the data is hidden.

I know i can get the future date with - `3.days.from_now`. But thats not exactly what i am looking for.

How do I show, how many days are remaning compared to the `created_at` from the database? The format that gets rendered the mysql db is `2013-06-06 19:41:02 UTC`. Now i want to show the time difference (in days) from this created_at date and time.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
((user.created_at + 3.days).to_date - Date.today).round
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what i was looking for :)

Comment: do you know how can i get hours here? instead of day.

Comment: I would highly appreciate your help on figuring out the no. of hours here too. Thanks again.

Comment: To get in hours `((user.created_at + 3.days - Time.now) / 1.hour).round`

Answer (score 1):

ActionView [has you covered](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words_to_now):

```
> Rails.helper.distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(3.days.from_now)
=> "3 days"

> Rails.helper.distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(8.hours.from_now)
=> "about 8 hours"

> Rails.helper.distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(12.weeks.ago)
=> "3 months"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
my_item.created_at + 3.days
```